# Django IOError - No such file or directory

Tags: django

I've read the previous threads on this topic and tried to modify the code, but no success again.
The problem is that I get `IOError message at %s. No such file or directory` error in the following view:

```
def some_view(request): 
   MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    with open(os.path.join(MYDIR, '/static/egais_files/client.xml'), 'w') as f:
    # ....
```

`client.xml` is located in the following folder:

```
\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\static\static\egais_files\client.xml
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE 1:**
The .py file containing `some_view` is located in `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\djprj\egais\views.py`

**UPDATE 2**. The settings.py file

```
import os   
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'supermarket_project.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","templates")],
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',                 
            ],},},]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'supermarket_project.wsgi.application'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
     )
```

Comment: You didn't provide where your .py file containing `some_view` is located.

Comment: See the updated question please

Comment: is file itself is located under `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj`?

Comment: Please see UPDATE 1 section of the question

Comment: Check the permissions on the file

Comment: Garfonzo, after long hour of research, I've managed to make Django see the file, and yet the error did not go away, but rather changed to `IOError 13 - permission denied`.

Answer (score 1):

Your source file is located in `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\djprj\egais\`, that means line:

```
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

will store that path in `MYDIR` variable, but your file is located in different directory. First, try to use:

```
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

that will give you path `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\`. Now, you should add one more `/static` to line:

```
with open(os.path.join(MYDIR, '/static/egais_files/client.xml'), 'w') as f:
```

so it will look like:

```
with open(os.path.join(MYDIR, '/static/static/egais_files/client.xml'), 'w') as f:
```

And it should give proper file path.

Comment: Nope. Won't work again. The strange think is that if I ran the project locally (reading the remote files), everything works fine. I mean, I copy the project as is on my PC, however, the files that are read are still located remotely. And all works fine. But I run it from 10.8.0.1 - nothing works

Comment: And still +1 for useful comments

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file containing some_view is located in `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\static\` you're not giving the right path.  I suspect it is in `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\` meaning you need to add '/static/' to the path.

Comment: Do you mean that it must be `(MYDIR, '/static/static/egais_files/client.xml')` instead of `(MYDIR, '/static/egais_files/client.xml')` ?

Comment: If that's what you mean, it did not work either. Now I am gonna update the question to include `settings.py` as well