# Django IOError 13 - permission denied when trying to write to static file

Tags: python, django

I've spent long hours trying to make Django open and write content into a remote file. This post can be considered as second part of the [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391507/django-ioerror-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment66112025_39391507) on the same topic. However, this time I managed to make Django see the file, and the error changed from 'IOError - such file or directory does not exist' to 
`IOError at /my_view/[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/test/djprj/djprj/static/media/my_target_file.xml`

The view (located in `\\10.8.0.1\share\djprj\djprj\djprj\egais`):

```
def my_view (request)
   #...
   with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'my_target_file.xml'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(html_content.encode('utf8'))
        f.close;
```

settings.py (only relevant part of it)

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...

ROOT_URLCONF = 'supermarket_project.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'supermarket_project.wsgi.application'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static-only")
#STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static-only")]
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","media")
#MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"media")]
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                      os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),"static","static"),
     )
```

Previously, my file was located in the static folder or the folder of the app itself, and Django could not find the file and/or folder for some reason. After moving it to Media, the error changed from "no such file or folder" to "permission denied".

**MOST IMPORTANT !**
When I copy the whole project and run it locally (the target file still remaining the remote one), all works just fine for me ! 
Could anyone suggest a way to solve this issue at last ? 
Even a hint towards what should be done, will be appreciated. I don't even know whether the reason is in Appache settings or there's something about Django itself.

**UPDATE:**
Even spacifying the full path does not solve the issue. Moreover, Django can't even see the file if I do.

Comment: What are the permissions on your media folder, and is it owned by the same user that runs django?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on the directory?  It sounds like that's what the problem here is.

Comment: I will be able to do that in several hours' time. Is it ok ?

Comment: Just post the information when you can get around to it.  I wouldn't expect an immediate response but someone will probably be on helping.